# Nested query with logic and summing the results

Tags: sql, sqlanywhere

Our accounting dept wants to add the tax collected or percentage for an item to the Consolidated Menu Item Sales Detail report. I have some experience with SQL, but it's been a long time since I used it on a regular basis and could use some help putting this query together. Below are the queries I put together to determine what tables and fields I need to work with. This is the menu item table. The obj_num is the primary key. The value will need to be a variable so it can run this for each item. Menu item table, var will be supplied by report process.

```
select * from micros.mi_def where obj_num='9230188'
```

I need the menu item class number to check the tax tables for which ones apply, so I can pass it to the next query. mi_type_seq is the menu item class number. The class controls taxes charged for that item. The item above has a menu class of 116, but this needs to work for whatever class the above item is.

```
select * from micros.mi_type_class_def where mi_type_seq='116'
```

tax_class is the menu item tax classification. This defines what taxes apply to that menu item class. Below I am passing '3" because that's the tax classification number for this item.

```
select * from micros.tax_class_def where tax_class_seq='3'
```

Result:

```
tax_class_seq,obj_num,name,ob_tax_1_active,ob_tax_2_active,ob_tax_3_active,ob_tax_4_active,ob_tax_5_active,ob_tax_6_active,ob_tax_7_active,ob_tax_8_active,ob_rsvd01,ob_rsvd02,ob_rsvd03,ob_rsvd04,ob_rsvd05,ob_rsvd06,ob_rsvd07,ob_rsvd08,last_updated_by,last_updated_date
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3,102,'Wine/Liqu Tax = State+Liq',**'T','T'**,'F','F','F','F','F','F','F','F','F','F','F','F','F','F',462,1997-06-16 16:06:18.437
```

What I really need here is probably an array to capture the values so I can query the percentages in the rate table. It could also work if I had a variable for hold the temp tax rate and retrieve the rate for each one marked true.
The 'T''s above in bold are the taxes that need to be charged. Those taxes defined in the tax_rate_def table. I only want to sum the values marked true above.

```
select * from micros.tax_rate_def
```

Table with tax rates.

Finally, sum the values that returned True. In this case, both rates in the field percentage from records that have seq 1 and 2 need to be totalled. The sum of the percentages that are marked as true is what I am trying to pull into the report.
select sum(percentage) from micros.tax_rate_def where tax_rate_seq between 1 and 2

We are using the Sybase DB that comes with Micros 5.7 build 5341. All help is appreciated. Thanks.
Andy

Comment: Hi Andy (@am_wg), I think it's hard to advise/answer without having relationship definition clearly between all those tables. Also, if you could post some sample data of each table and desired result that would help us lot to serve you better. thanks

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you mention you're using Sybase but tagged the question as (MS) SQL-Server; which RDBMS are you using? If 'Sybase', which product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version?

Comment: Sample data from the first table.
17736,8007532,Tws cbl o f c a,112
17737,8007533,Tws pom hat,112
17738,8007534,Tws chn p l f a,112
17739,8007535,Twos open wv sha,112
17740,8521685,Tws octps bnc b,112
17741,8520065,Tws fish dish,112
17742,8520066,Tws shell dish,112
17743,8007536,Bd LT Lmn T 6 B,189
17744,8007537,M U I L&P P 6 B,189

Second data set from second query.
184,701,Tobacco,15
188,778,Market Lotto Not Taxable,4
189,702,Alcohol,15
179,777,Market Lottery Open NoTaxable,4
180,204,Citrus Liquor Item LEVELS,3

Comment: Sample data from second table
184,701,Tobacco,15
188,778,Market Lotto Not Taxable,4
189,702,Alcohol,15
179,777,Market Lottery Open NoTaxable,4
180,204,Citrus Liquor Item LEVELS,3

Comment: 3rd data set provided above. 
4th data set.
1,Food Tax 6.5%,Fd Tx 6.5.%,Food Sales,6.5000
2,Alcohol Tax 6.5%,Alc Tax 6.5%,Alc Sales,6.5000
3,Retail Tax 6.5%,Ret Tx 6.5.%,Ret Net Sls,6.5000
4,Food Tax Incl Cafe,Incl Fd T Tx,Incl Fd Sls,6.5000

Comment: SQLAnywhere 17 is the db